# GNU Octave figure with thick frame

Tags: plot, octave, fltk

I am trying to make a figure that uses a somewhat thicker line for the frame / axes than the lines used for the grid. I tried plotting a rectangle with thick lines to mimic the figure frame. This almost works perfectly, but the lower right corner does not come out well. The lines don't meet nicely (see attachment).

Here's an example to illustrate the problem:

```
plot (rand(1,5),'-o' , 'Linewidth',2); % plot some data
grid on % show grid lines (thin)
r = axis(); % find the coordinates of the figure frame
rectangle ( 'Position',[r(1) r(3) r(2)-r(1) r(4)-r(3)] , 'Linewidth',5 ) % plot the figure frame using thick lines
print ('test.png') % save to file
```

Any ideas how to make this work?

[image]

Comment: looks like your installed gl2ps doesn't `setlinecap` to 2. Which gl2ps version do you have?

Comment: I don't know. How can I tell?

Answer (score 2):

Get the current `axes` object for the plot and set its `linewidth` property.

```
set(gca, 'linewidth', 5)
```

**UPDATE**:

Try overlaying axes to get the effect you want as in the comments. This kind of approach will work, but alas, usually tweaking will be involved to get things right. If you have a consistent use-case perhaps you could automate this with a script.

```
% the "frame" axis
a = axes; 
a_pos = get (a, 'position')
set (a, 'color', 'black', 'xtick', [], 'ytick', []);

% the "white background" axis; sits on top of "a"'s black background
b = axes ()
set (b, 'position', a_pos + [0.01, 0.01, -0.02, -0.02], 'color', 'w', 'xtick', [], 'ytick', []);

% the "actual" axis; transparent so that its background is effectively from "b"
c = axes;
plot (c, rand(1,5),'-o' , 'Linewidth',2); % plot some data
set (c, 'position', a_pos, 'xgrid', 'on', 'ygrid', 'on', 'color', 'none');
```

Comment: That will also increase the linewidth of the grid lines, and that's not what I want. In addition, this results in the same "corner problem", but this time at ALL FOUR corners of the frame.

Comment: @mbrennwa you're right, the corners I consider an octave bug of sorts. With regard to the gridlines, you can always overlay an empty axis over another; this is a very common technique for mixing up plot elements when `hold` isn't enough. The only other option I can think of here is to place a "black" axis below your axis of interest. I'll give an example above in a sec.

Comment: The update with the overlay axes achieves what I described in my question. It seems a bit more complex than it should be though, just to avoid the Octave quirk with the poor line joints at the corners. It might also be tricky to set the thickness of the frame to a given line width. But thanks!

Comment: Agreed. For what it's worth though, I'm under the impression that the poor line joints are an upstream problem with the postscript library rather than an octave-specific problem. I think matlab behaves the same way (but I may be wrong).  EDIT: ah, no it doesn't. Perhaps it might be worth reporting this as a bug in the octave bug-tracker then?